# How to deploy project artifacts into an IIS server (across tenant) via azure release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My client has got an Azure VM in their tenant, with .NET installed and IIS configured.

I am using Azure Devops build/release pipeline on another tenant. Build pipeline generates an artifact (zip file). Now I want to deploy the zip contents into the IIS.

What do I need to do to make my release pipeline be able to deploy the website into the IIS VM which is on another azure tenant?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can create a Deployment Group in Azure VM and then you can use Deployment Group job in Release Pipeline to deploy the zip package to Azure VM IIS.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create a Deployment Group target in Azure VM. [Create a deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=net#create-a-deployment-group)

Step2: In Release Pipeline, you can use [IIS web app manage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) and [IIS web app deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops)  to deploy the Zip contents to Azure VM IIS.

For example:

[image]

For more detailed steps, you can refer to this doc: [Deploy apps to a Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=net#create-a-deployment-group)

This way will not be limited by tenant.

Comment: In the Azure VM I need to install the deployment group software?

Comment: Yes. this is similar to self-hosted agent